# Display change between two rows of a column in oracle with select statement

Tags: oracle

I have a history table which stores the changes
it has id, change_count, perform, perform_comment

it has values like this

> 1011, 0, null, null --> this row is with basic information 1011, 1,
> null, info added --> stored a change with perform_comment 1011, 2, Y,
> info added --> stored a change with perform

now I want to display data for id what has changed like

> id, null ->Y, null -> info added

I have tried with joins, lag function but no success in oracle

Comment: How do you want to "display" that "data"? Do you mean, in a single row of text, with arrows and all? I assume not. Please show EXACTLY how you want the output to look. Also, do you need to do this for just one id (given at runtime, perhaps), or for all id's? In all cases, the task seems trivial - order by (id and) change_count, but select only (id and) perform and perform_comment, `order by (id, ) change_count`.

Comment: actually I am able to display using left joins and adding max(perfom_count) and max(perform_count)-1 in where condition. So that I am able to display the content in same row

Comment: did you make it work? if not please post table definition, sample data a required output